# Good way to isolate hard drive sound

Tags: hard-drive, noise

What is the best method to isolate hard drive sound (almost) completely?

I’m thinking about creating a hard drive case with isolation material.

- What material is the best for isolating a hard drive
- How thick does the isolation need to be?
- Do I need to keep a part of the case open so that heat can get out? Or does this let a lot of sound out?

I did some more research, there is a solution for this. You can put your hard drive in a special case which will cancel sounds. The product is called: Smart Drive Neo. But I can't find a reseller for this product in my country.

Comment: You can buy `sound proof` casing (tower) - I have this as I record in the same room as the computer - it does not totally reduce the sound but it does help (the only sound I really get now is from the fans).

Answer (score 3):

A few possibilities:

- Use an anti-vibration mounting frame (it will isolate the vibrations from the case)
  for best results, you will need a 5.25-slot for a 3.5 harddrive.
- Use anti-vibration pins, not the "normal screws" for mounting the hdd.
- You can isolate the whole case.
- Buy a new case. (*reviews out there will help you to find a good one*)
- Find out if  your hdd supports  silent mode. (*but , then it will be a little slower*)

Answer (score 2):

user3107377 has some great suggestions. I’ll mention the steps I used for my system. I did a few simple (and cheap) things to cut down the vibrations and sound from my system (which came mostly from the hard-drive and fans), and sometimes I forget it’s even on (at least until it heats up and the CPU fan kicks in or I defrag my older, worn out drive).

- Insert rubber washers between the drive and drive case
- Don’t tighten screws all the way (which only helps to conduct the vibrations to the case). Of course you need rubber washers for this to work well, per the previous point
- Mount a 3.5" drive in a 5.25" bracket to have more control
- Use rubber feet on the bottom of the case instead of the hard-plastic feet that come with cheaper cases
- Place the case on a soft surface instead of a hard wood desk (free under-padding remnants from a carpet store works great)

And yes, you’ll probably need to leave some ventilation holes for airflow for proper cooling, unless you opt to use water-cooling, in which case you can not only completely close up the case, but you can forgo fans altogether which reduces system noise even further. As others have mentioned, you can also engage your hard-drive’s [AAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_acoustic_management) (automatic acoustic management) function if it supports it (though be aware that while it reduces noise, it also reduces performance slightly), or just use an SSD which is completely silent.

Answer (score 1):

If you completely encase the HDD then heat will become an issue.

If you leave ventilation then sound will escape

Catch 22.

Your best solution is SSD - completely silent.

Comment: Smart Drive Neo is a product that does this. I want to create one on my own because I can't buy that product in my country. I want to store at least 1 TB data. It is to expansive for me to buy a 1TB SSD.

Comment: Heat is not realy an issue: http://www.quietpc.com/smartdrive-neo-qq

Comment: "if you completely encase the HDD then heat will become an issue" - what do you base that statement on? I think you are wrong. If you encase your drive in heatsinks and thermal pads, the sound will be reduced little or no air will escape and heat will not be an issue. Even if you wrap it in foam and cellophane, nothing terrible will happen. Of course, different disks produce different amounts of heat so my statement are also questionable.

Answer (score 0):

Soundproofing mechanical, spinning drives is tricky.

In a home-macgyver type of situation I have found that putting the whole box inside another box or even a closet / cabinet gives good results. If you can additionally suspend the box with drives on rubbers (such as you use to fasten things to a bike or a car) then vibrations from the drives/box will not reach your walls and floor.

In my most recent build (space constrained, and no closet space) I have added a self-adhesive vinyl-rubbery sound dampening material on the outside of the computer case, which helps. This material is intended for sound-insulating the outer body of personal cars and is much, much cheaper than "sound proofing foam" one may find on computer hardware websites. However, this material is very heavy and unsafe close to heat sources, but you can read the instructions on your own... look for "car sound insulation alubutyl". Additionally, you can throw a thick yoga mat over the box to help with the medium-pitched sounds. Obviously this looks quite ghetto.

Some theory:

- https://www.soundproofcow.com/difference-high-middle-low-frequency-noise/
- https://www.explainthatstuff.com/soundproofing.html
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_reduction_index

tldr: I think drives produce sound waves in all three frequency bands

- low 0-500 (heads seeking)
- middle 500-2000 (heads writing, reading)
- high 2000-20k+ (engine spinning platters or platters interacting with air)

So we need materials that block all types of sound waves which is not easy / cheap to get in a compact form. Generally dense and thin layers of rubber or vinyl or plastic foam can help with high-frequency sounds (disks accelerating, coil whine), thicker materials help with medium pitched sounds while low-pitch sounds are notoriously hard to stop (think whale speech, neighbor's bass).